# Which one to use ID token or access token while calling backend API?

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, azure-entra-id

From Azure AD documentation I understand that ID token is for authentication and access token is what you send to the backend API for authorization.

But I have several APIs which gives response based on the roles of the user who is logged in. I have configured the roles in the Service Principal under App roles as seen in the below picture.

[image]

And when the user authenticates, the ID token contains the roles as seen below.

[image]

Currently, I send the ID token in the Authorization header and then the backend decodes and validates the token and based on the roles, it sends appropriate response.

But I was not able to find any documentation to justify this solution. If there is a better/proper solution on how to implement this, please do guide me! Or is there a way to send roles from access token?

Comment: Make use of access token to call the backend API. Refer https://community.auth0.com/t/using-idtoken-to-access-internal-api/87256 and https://auth0.com/blog/why-should-use-accesstokens-to-secure-an-api/

Comment: @Rukmini. I referred the documents you sent, I understand the functionality of access token and ID token but can you please help with the part where I have mentioned the roles which are essential in formulation the response body for an API because the roles come in ID token in azure AD

Comment: But to access backend API it is suggested to pass access token instead of ID token. You have to assign roles to the user in Enterprise application and the pass scope as api://xxx/.default and access token will contain roles

Comment: This is the access token with [**roles**](https://i.imgur.com/pic7few.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: You have to make use of access token to call the backend API. Refer this [**blog**](https://auth0.com/blog/why-should-use-accesstokens-to-secure-an-api/) by Maria Paktiti.

If you want the roles to be present in access token, then try the below:

Created a Microsoft Entra ID application and added **app role**:

[image]

Now, I **assigned the role to the user** in Enterprise application:

[image]

And granted API permissions:

[image]

Generated **access and ID tokens** like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID  
scope:api://ID/.default openid offline_access
grant_type:authorization_code  
code:code  
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:Secret
```

[image]

***When I decoded the access token, role is displayed:***

[image]

*Even in the ID token role is displayed:*

[image]

Hence, to have role-based authorization you can make use of access token.